# RHEL5's zlib differ in file size

Tags: redhat

G'day,

while investigating unexpected behaviour on one particular RHEL 5 instance I came across the irritating fact that the file size of `/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3` differs on some RHEL 5 instances, although the RPM package is reported to be identicl, with identical build dates.  My own RHEL with package `zlib-1.2.3-3.i386.rpm` as well as one installation at a customer site has a `libz.so.1.2.3` of 75284 bytes:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 75284 19. Jul 2006  /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```

On another RHEL 5 instance with the identical package version the same file has 73836 bytes:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73836 Jul 19  2006 /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```

When extracting the rpm file using

```
rpm2cpio zlib-1.2.3-3.i386.rpm | cpio -idv
```

the shared library is created with a size of 73836 bytes, so I assume, this size is correct.  However, the same file on most other installations have a size of 75284 bytes.

Does anybody have a clue why this is the case?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [prelink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink).

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Well, according to the article, prelink modifies ELF binaries. If information is added to the binary, its size increases.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your input (I haven't noticed there was a hyperlink, sorry). However, I have another question: if I understand the article correctly, prelinking affects the executable, not the shared libraries. Or are they also modified?

Comment: From `prelink(8)`: "prelink is a program that modifies ELF shared libraries and ELF dynamically linked binaries..."

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It appears that someone (or somewhat) has modified /etc/sysconfig/prelink to disable prelink on our customer's box. Now I have to find out who and why! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to determine if a file provided by an RPM has been modified on the file system:

```
rpm -qVv zlib.i386
```

It will produce results similar to this:

```
[msavona@admina03:~]$ rpm -qVv zlib.i386
........    /usr/lib/libz.so.1
........    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
........    /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3
........  d /usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README
```

Where the periods represent:
file size, mode, md5 checksum, symlink, device, user, group, modified time

If you see something that looks like this:

```
S.5.....    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```

Then the filesize and MD5 checksum differs between the file provided by the RPM and the file as it resides on the file system.

If the file on the file system does indeed differ, something external (outside of RPMs management) altered this file.

For what it's worth, on a RHEL5 system (zlib-1.2.3-3.i386 package), here's what my file looks like (from rpm -q --dump zlib.i386):

```
/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3 73836 1153298282 02864132ee9f24adcf3502be355c633b 0100755 root root 0 0 0 X
```

Comment: prelink also modifies the rpmdb, so this check is less than reliable in that sense.

Comment: I am unable to comment or up-vote your answer Ignacio because I don't have enough reputation, but you are indeed correct. The following proves it: prelink -y /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3 >/tmp/libz.so.1.2.3.tmp && md5sum /tmp/libz.so.1.2.3.tmp && rm /tmp/libz.so.1.2.3.tmp . The resultant md5sum is 02864132ee9f24adcf3502be355c633b which is the original MD5 sum contained within the RPM. As such, Ignacio's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Even better than my last comment, use this single command: prelink --md5 -y /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3